# Perl sequence alignment score calculation error

Tags: perl

Hello I'm writing this program for my Bioinformatics class, where I get a sequence from a text file and then mutate the sequence. After that I'm suppose to do a comparison to make a score by comparing the base pairs. I have all the code written, but I do not understand why I keep getting the score of 0. I'm assuming that the part of my code that deals with this is wrong because I initialized the `$sum = 0;` I was wondering if I could get some help to fix this issue so that my code works properly. Here is the sequence I'm using.

```
AGGGCACCTCTCAGTTCTCATTCTAACACCACATAATTTTTATTTGTATTATTCAGATTTTTCATGAACTTTTCCACAT
AGAATGAAGTTGACATTGTTATTTCTCAGGGTCTCGGTTCACCAGTATTTGACAAACTTGAAGCTGAACTAGCTAAAGC
```

```
use strict;

my $sum = 0;
my @seq;
my $seqString;
my $seqShuf;
my $line;

unless(open FILE, "test_seq.txt")
{
    print "Cannot open file!";
    exit; 
}

while (chomp($line = <FILE>))
{
    next if (/^>/);
    @seq = <FILE>;
}

$seqString = join("",@seq);
chomp($seqShuf = shuffle_string($seqString));
$seqShuf =~ s/\s+//g;
#print "Original sequence is:\n";
#print "$seqString\n";
#print "Mutated Sequence is:\n";
#print "$seqShuf\n";

my @shufSeq = split("", $seqShuf, length($seqShuf));

my %test = (
            AA => 0,
            AG => -1,
            AT => -2,
            AC => -2,
            GA => -1,
            GG => 0,
            GT => -2,
            GC => -2,
            TA => -2,
            TG => -2,
            TT => 0,
            TC => -1,
            CA => -2,
            CG => -2,
            CT => -1,
            CC => 0
            );

my @base_pairs = make_base_pairs(@seq, @shufSeq);
foreach my $bp (@base_pairs)
{
    $sum += $test{$bp};
}

print "@base_pairs\n";
print "The score is ", $sum, "\n";

# Shuffles original sequence
sub shuffle_string
{
    my ($string) = @_;
    my $length = length $string;
    for (my $i = 0; $i < $length-1; $i++)
    {
        my $j = random_int ($i, $length-1);
        my $tmp = substr($string, $i, 1);
        substr($string, $i, 1) = substr($string, $j, 1);
        substr($string, $j, 1) = $tmp;
    }
    return $string;
}

# created random int between two parameters
sub random_int
{
    (my $par1, my $par2) = @_;
    my $num = (1+$par1) +  int(rand($par2 - $par1));
}

# aligns base pairs based on index location
sub make_base_pairs
{
    (my @orig, my @shuf) = @_;
    my $idx = 0;
    my @bps;
    foreach my $base (@orig)
    {
        push @bps, $base , $shuf[$idx];
        $idx++;
    }
    return @bps;
}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug your program?

Comment: `use warnings;` is even more important than strict

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the number of simple perl bugs, not to mention some algorithm ones are too numerous to list. Just study and compare the code below.

Here's the cleaned up code. It may still have some bugs, but at least it prints non-zero [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $sum = 0;
my @seq;
my $seqString;
my $seqShuf;
my $line;

open(FILE, "test_seq.txt") or
    die("unable to open file -- $!\n");

while ($line = <FILE>) {
    chomp($line);
    push(@seq,split(//,$line));
}

close(FILE);

my @shufSeq = shuffle_string(@seq);
#print "Original sequence is:\n";
#print "$seqString\n";
#print "Mutated Sequence is:\n";
#print "$seqShuf\n";

my %test = (
AA => 0,
    AG => -1,
    AT => -2,
    AC => -2,
    GA => -1,
    GG => 0,
    GT => -2,
    GC => -2,
    TA => -2,
    TG => -2,
    TT => 0,
    TC => -1,
    CA => -2,
    CG => -2,
    CT => -1,
    CC => 0
);

my @base_pairs = make_base_pairs(\@seq, \@shufSeq);
foreach my $bp (@base_pairs)
{
    ###printf("DEBUG bp='%s'\n",$bp);
    $sum += $test{$bp};
}

print("base_pairs: ",join(" ",@base_pairs),"\n");
print "The score is ", $sum, "\n";

# Shuffles original sequence
sub shuffle_string
{
    my (@string) = @_;
    my $length = @string;

    for (my $i = 0; $i < $length-1; $i++) {
        my $j = random_int ($i, $length-1);

        my $tmp = $string[$i];
        $string[$i] = $string[$j];
        $string[$j] = $tmp;
    }

    @string;
}

# created random int between two parameters
sub random_int
{
    my($par1,$par2) = @_;
    my $num = (1+$par1) +  int(rand($par2 - $par1));
    $num;
}

# aligns base pairs based on index location
sub make_base_pairs
{
    my($orig,$shuf) = @_;
    my $idx = 0;
    my @bps;

    foreach my $base (@$orig) {
        push(@bps,$base . $shuf->[$idx]);
        $idx++;
    }

    return @bps;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> This helps a ton thank you so much. This is my first programming class and its been killing me all semester. I'll keep looking at the code and editing to get rid of some of the extra bugs.

Below are some additional notes that may help with the understanding of the mechanics of the changes I made.

Now that the program is basically working, you can check to see if your randomization and shuffle code are algorithmically adequate (i.e. sufficiently random and the shuffle works).

For example, I think the last element of the shuffle will *always* be the last element of the original, because the `i` loop is `< $length-1` instead of `< $length`. I tried to fix this by looping one more, but got an out-of-bounds on the array.

---

**File I/O:**

The code to read in file data and split on single characters is pretty idiomatic.

In your code, the `@seq = <FILE>` would only give you an array of one with the text of the last line [because the first line was pulled by the `$line = <FILE>`].

Looping on the `chomp` value is not the best criterion for the loop. It [maybe, sort of] works, but I've never done it that way.

The `next if` would do nothing because it would operate on `$_` and not `$line` [and why have it at all?].

So, at the end, `@seq` would have a single element that was the last line [*without* a newline strip], instead of all characters of the file split into one character per `@seq` element.

Since `@seq` still had a newline, that's probably why you had a second `chomp` later

---

**Shuffle:**

The main change to `shuffle_seq` is to operate by indexing into an array instead of using `substr` to swap within a scalar. In your code, you did a `join` on `@seq` just to call `shuffle_seq` and then did a `split` on the result. By having `shuffle_seq` work on arrays, things are simpler.

---

**Syntax:**

I've never seen `(my $par1, my $par2) = @_;` syntax before [it might be valid--I didn't check]. I just use `my($par1,$par2) = @_;`

---

**make_base_pair:**

In your `make_base_pairs`, *all* elements of *both* `@seq` and `@shufSeq` would end up in make_base_pair's `@orig` and its `@shuf` would be empty.

I changed the sequence to `make_base_pair(\@seq,\@shufSeq)` [with a corresponding change inside the function]. This passes a scalar *reference* to each array, rather than passing the array values.

Note that with references, inside the function, the syntax to access changes to `@$orig` and `$shuf->[$idx]`

With these changes, the algorithmic results are more likely to be correct.

Without them, `make_base_pairs` would still operate, but it had one final bug that was the show stopper:

Your `push` would add *two* elements on each loop: `X,""` [remember that `@shuf` was empty]. So, the end result was an array of single char elements [or empty] and *not* array elements that were *two* characters as you desired.

My change to the push: `push(@bps,$base . $shuf->[$idx]);` uses perl's string *concatenation* operator: `.` to concatenate `base` and `shuf` [which are a single character each] to produce two character output elements.

The main bug was that `make_base_pairs` was returning an array that had *no* two character elements, so the loop to sum them could *never* produce non-zero.

Comment: This helps a ton thank you so much. This is my first programming class and its been killing me all semester. I'll keep looking at the code and editing to get rid of some of the extra bugs.